# Stored Procedure only authenticates first user in tblUsers

Tags: sql-server, validation, stored-procedures, authentication

I have a stored procedure which authenticates users on the login page.The proc first checks if the email exists in the table,if it doesnt exist,it gives out

```
  Select 0 as EmailExists
```

and if the email exists,it goes on with checking for correct password and so on.My entire proc is given below.The problem is validates the first user in tblUsers and shows EmailExists as 0 for all other users.Why is that?

```
Alter proc spValidateUser
    @EmailAdd nvarchar(20),
    @Password nvarchar(20)
as
begin
    Set Nocount on;
    Declare @EmailExists bit,@UserId nvarchar(10),@LastLogin datetime,@RoleId int,@AccountLocked bit,@RetryCount int
    if exists(Select 1 from tblAllUsers where EmailAdd=@EmailAdd)
    begin
        Select @AccountLocked=IsLocked from tblAllUsers where EmailAdd=@EmailAdd
        ----if account is already locked------
        if(@AccountLocked = 1)
        begin
            Select 1 as AccountLocked,0 as Authenticated,0 as RetryAttempts,1 as EmailExists
        end
        else
        begin
            -----check if username and password match-----
            Select @UserId = UserId, @LastLogin=LastLogin, @RoleId=RoleId
            from tblAllUsers where EmailAdd=@EmailAdd and Password=@Password
            ----if match found--------
            If @UserId is not null
            Begin
                Update tblAllUsers
                SET LastLogin= GETDATE(),RetryAttempts=0 WHERE UserId=@UserId
                Select @UserId [UserId],
                (Select Role from tblRoles 
                  where RoleId=@RoleId) 
                 [Roles],0 as AccountLocked,1 as Authenticated,0 as RetryAttempts,1 as EmailExists
            End
            Else
            ------if match not found--------
            Begin
                Select @RetryCount=ISNULL(RetryAttempts,0) from tblAllUsers where EmailAdd=@EmailAdd
                Set @RetryCount=@RetryCount+1
                if(@RetryCount<=3)
                Begin
                    ----if retry attempts are not completed------
                    Update tblAllUsers Set RetryAttempts=@RetryCount where EmailAdd=@EmailAdd

                    Select 0 as AccountLocked,0 as Authenticated,@RetryCount as RetryAttempts,1 as EmailExists
                End
                Else
                Begin
                    ------if retry attempts are completed--------
                    Update tblAllUsers Set RetryAttempts=@RetryCount,IsLocked=1,LockedDateTime=GETDATE()
                    where EmailAdd=@EmailAdd

                    Select 1 as AccountLocked,0 as Authenticated,0 as RetryAttempts,1 as EmailExists
                End
            End
        End
    end
    Else
    begin
        Select 0 as EmailExists
    end
end
```

Comment: You really need to stop storing passwords in plain text. They should be salted and hashed. It is not clear what your issue is here though.

Comment: Please fix your code indenting. I already did that for your last question about the same procedure...

Comment: Your procedure seems to return a result set with 1, 4 or 5 columns depending on the case. Does your application really support that?

Comment: Sir, listen to  @JamesZ - your code indenting is awful, you must really do something about that. I formatted your code now .... I ONLY formatted it, changed nothing else. You are pretty lucky: I did it only so that I can remove my downvote. And that's only since I became converted and convinced that downvotes are inhumane.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can see EmailExists is showing 0 for every email address, is if this statement is evaluating to false.  Which means, the email address being entered does not exist in tblAllUsers.

```
if exists(Select 1 from tblAllUsers where EmailAdd=@EmailAdd)
begin
    ...
Else
   Select 0 as EmailExists
End
```

If you believe this is not the case, then post some table data for email addresses you are having problems with.

Comment: I have tested the above condition.It gives out 1 when the email exists and 0 when the email doesn't exist.It works just fine.It is only when i put it to work inside a stored procedure it is giving out improper results.

Comment: Then give us some more code and examples to work with.  Post the code you are executing, and show us the data that is failing.